Interpretation of a PDF
I have the probability density function (PDF)
$$\frac{6}{5}(e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}),x>0 \text{ and 0 otherwise}$$
If I compare this to the two individual component PDFs:
$$2e^{-2x},x>0 \text{ and 0 otherwise}$$
$$3e^{-3x},x>0 \text{ and 0 otherwise}$$
it seems that the relation is:
$$\text{Reciprocal of }\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=6/5$$
Is this some property or is there an interpretation of this in terms of random variables or the real world?

I don't think it's anything special - just a normalizing constant to make sure it is a valid PDF.

It is a mixture of two Exponential distributions.

@StubbornAtom Indeed.  This mixture distribution is a $\frac35:\frac25$ mixture of those two exponential distributions.

The mixture comment was very, very helpful. If you write it as an answer, I can accept it.

A harmonic sum of 2 and 3. Related to harmonic average / harmonic mean.

You need the pdf to integrate to $1$ over its support, which here is $x \ge 0$. Since

$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-2x}\, dx = \frac12$ and $\frac{1}{\frac12}=2$, the corresponding pdf is $2e^{-2x}$

$\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-3x}\, dx = \frac13$ and $\frac{1}{\frac13}=3$, the corresponding pdf is $3e^{-3x}$

$\int\limits_0^\infty \left(e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}\right)\, dx = \frac12+\frac13=\frac56$ and $\frac{1}{\frac12+\frac13}=\frac{1}{\frac56}=\frac65$, the corresponding pdf is $\frac65\left(e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}\right)$


$\dfrac{1}{\frac12+\frac13}=\dfrac65$ is the result you observed and is a consequence of the pdfs having to integrate to $1$.
As @StubbornAtom commented, the combined pdf represents a mixture of the two original exponential distributions.  In effect you have a probability of $\frac35$ of drawing from the first density of $2e^{-2x}$ and a probability of $\frac25$ from the second density of $3e^{-3x}$, making the combined density $$\frac35\times 2e^{-2x} +\frac25\times 3e^{-3x} \\= \frac65\left(e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}\right).$$
